# Like comparing the color of a pixel of a bitmap image with the color of a Brushes

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm having the following problem: I need to build a method that takes as a parameter an `BITMAP` and `BRUSHES`. In this method I have to compare the color of each pixel with the brushes of color that was passed in the parameter. How do I do that? So far I only have the code below ready:

```
public static int FindPixelsColor(Bitmap image, System.Windows.Media.Brushes color)
    {
        var qt = 0;
        for (var x = 0; x < image.Width; x++)
        {
            for (var y = 0; y < image.Height; y++)
            {
                var currentPixel = image.GetPixel(x, y);
                //If this color the pixel is equal to brush the color increments the variable qt
            }
        }
        return qt;
    }
```

For bitmap image I'm using `System.Drawing`;

Comment: What problem are you having trouble with? Have you looked at the docs for the color and brush classes?

Comment: The `Brushes` class contains a static set of brushes, i.e. all named colors. Why do you send that into the method, and do you want to compare the pixel color with all the colors?

Comment: Just need to know how I will compare the color of the current pixel with the brushes of color. If they are equal, only increase the QT variable. I do not know how to do an if for this comparison @Guffa

Comment: @ZongZhengLi With the color I can make the comparison. I will try to convert the brush in a color. Because this method is to a very great job. I can not modify a BRUSHE on a COLOR it does not affect the box functionality.

Comment: So the problem is that you don't know how to extract the color of the brush? If there exists some method, use it, otherwise you can use the brush to draw on a temporary image to determine its color.

Comment: `System.Windows.Media` is a WPF namespace, is this WPF?

Comment: The `Brushes` class doesn't contain one brush, it contains 141 brushes. They are however static properties, so you can't just iterate through them. Did you mean to use the `Brush` class?